# How to get YT video location?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I try to get the location of a given video with YT API

I see it on the API overview, but not in the JSON overview:

[image]

but:

[image]

How can I get it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official API [Revision History](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) doc, the information of your interest is not provided by the API for quite some time:

> [**June 1, 2017**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#june-1,-2017)
>
> This update contains the following changes:
>
> **Note:** This is a deprecation announcement.
>
> The following [`video`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) resource properties are being deprecated. While the properties will be supported until December 1, 2017, there is no guarantee that videos will continue to return values for those properties until that time. Similarly, [`videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and [`videos.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) requests that set those property values will not generate errors before that date, but it is possible that the incoming data will not be stored.
>
> - [`recordingDetails.locationDescription`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#recordingDetails.locationDescription)
> - [`recordingDetails.location.latitude`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#recordingDetails.location.latitude)
> - [`recordingDetails.location.longitude`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#recordingDetails.location.longitude)

In my experience, there are still videos out there that have that info returned when invoking the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint, but know no official explanation of that.

For example, the one that has the ID `7huCin676dA` still has `recordingDetails` attached:

```
$ wget -qO- --content-on-error \
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=$YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY&id=7huCin676dA&part=recordingDetails&fields=items/recordingDetails&maxResults=1"
{
  "items": [
    {
      "recordingDetails": {
        "locationDescription": "Tremola Passstrasse",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 46.545149,
          "longitude": 8.5694851,
          "altitude": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can I get a country name somehow? not so specific coordinates?

Comment: No, the `recordingDetails` object did not contained the country code; but I guess that this info can be derived from `latitude` and `longitude`, isn't it?

Comment: By calling to which another API?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't yet had to do this myself. However, I hope this may help: [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse).